# How to sync iPod Touch with iOS 5?

Tags: 10.04, ipod

I have an iPod touch with iOS 5 and I want to be able to put music and and videos on it but never figured out how. Can someone help me?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the guide [here](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/howto/sync-your-iphone-or-ipod-touch-in-ubuntu/) to sync music, videos, etc. on your iDevice.

Comment: It is still not letting me. I followed the instructions and it doesn't even recognize it.

Comment: @David You need to unmark this question as solved, otherwise it won't show up on the unanswered list.

Comment: Oh sorry. I still have not been able to figure this out. Please help me!

Comment: Do I need to have Ubuntu 10.10? I have 10.04

Comment: Nothing to do with the Ubuntu-version.

Answer (score 0):

libgpod is the library most of the major linux media players use to sync iOS devices, but it doesn't even support iOS4 at the moment. libimobiledevice, which supports up to 4.0.3.3 doesn't support it yet either, but it looks like it'll have it up and running sooner than libgpod.

The obvious workaround until one of them gets their act together is to install iTunes using wine (urgh) -- or install OSX on virtualbox (but that seems a little extreme for just iPod syncing). I was going to say to install some other windows based media player, but I've done a search and none of them are supporting it either.

Comment: This is not completely right. It has more to do with the device. With The iPod Nano 6G for example it's the same. If you have an iPhone 3GS with iOS 4 it will sync right. Has something to do with how the newest devices communicate.